# Https request not working in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http, https

In my node.js app, I want to make an https api call. I am trying with the `https` module and it is not working, but then I try with a `request` module, and that works.

not work

```
var options = {
    host : 'myserver/platform-api/v1',
    port : 80,
    path : '/projects?access_token=38472',
    method : 'GET',
    headers : {
        'Accept' : 'application/json'
    }
};
var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log(chunk);
    });
});
req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log('problem with request:', e.message);
});
req.end();
```

I get this

```
problem with request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND myserver/platform-api/v1
 myserver/platform-api/v1:80
```

this works

```
request("https://myserver/platform-api/v1/projects?access_token=38472", function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) return console.log(error);
    //console.log(error);
    //console.log(response);
    console.log(body);
});
```

I can't figure out why it does not work on the first one. Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of passing options as a param maybe pass options.path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** Switched to port 443 as well.

---

Your `host` seemed to include part of the path? Try this instead (left just the host in `host` and moved the path to `path`):

```
var options = {
    host : 'myserver',
    port : 443,
    path : '/platform-api/v1/projects?access_token=38472',
    method : 'GET',
    headers : {
        'Accept' : 'application/json'
    }
};
```

Comment: Why are you passing everything in the object wouldn't all those properties be defined elsewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. `port` defaults to 443, so that could be omitted. Is that what you mean?

Comment: thanks, it was the port and I had part of the path in the host.

Comment: I am not as familiar with this format so I was just asking why you're defining host, path, method etc. all as a parameter in the objects properties in the HTTP request.  My thought is this would be defined elsewhere, so you can just do the simple GET, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, etc. It looks more like an AJAX call.

Comment: Should also probably educate myself a bit more on the subject, node. It's a pretty general question.

Comment: @DylanWright I'd recommend submitting your own question, as this doesn't seem related to the issue being discussed here.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you're hitting port 80, which is usually not the HTTPS port.

Comment: ok thanks i figured it out, it was port 443 and I had part of the path in the host.